# Progress Dialog with spinner not working

Tags: android

How to get the current value of the progress dialog when using spinner in a progress dialog?
I am trying to read the current value by progressdialog.getProgress() method it is working fine for horizontal style but not for spinner style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner style progress bars are *indeterminate*, which means they are endlessly spinning until you stop them. They don't display a certain progress, they just show there is an action going on that might take some time. Thus, you cannot retrieve (or set) any progress from (to) them.